# I keep getting "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error in delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, error-handling, delphi-2010

Whenever this code runs the I get the above error. The code is supposed to insert a record into a table and then delete records from another table.

```
for I := iMax - K to iMax do
begin
  Inc(a);
  with dmMenu.qryMcDonalds do
  begin
    SQL.Text :=
      'SELECT ID, ItemID, ItemPrice, ItemCategory FROM tblCheckout WHERE ID = ' + IntToStr(I);
    Open;
    sItemID := Fields[1].AsString;
    rItemPrice := Fields[2].AsFloat;
    sItemCategory := Fields[3].AsString;

    ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
     // I get the error here
    SQL.Text :=
      'INSERT INTO tblOrderItems (OrderItemID, OrderID, ItemID, ItemCategory, ItemPrice) VALUES ("' + sOrderID + '_' + IntToStr(a) + '"' + ', "' + sOrderID + '", "' + sItemID + '", "' + sItemCategory + '", "' + FloatToStrF(rItemPrice, ffCurrency, 10, 2) + '")';
    ExecSQL;

    SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM tblCheckout WHERE ID = ' + IntToStr(I); 
    ExecSQL;
  end; // with SQL 
end; // for I
```

edit: I think i the problem is in the 'INSERT INTO' part. All the columns are short text except the last one, ItemPrice is a currency. I am also using Access

Comment: Notice that this code can be used for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: We can't see your screen - on which exact line does the error occur?  If it is the 'INSERT INTO ...' one, replace this with a properly parameterised INSERT statement and your problem will disappear in an instant.

Comment: Btw, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: @MartynA I get the error at the 'DELETE FROM' part

Comment: Are you sure it is that statement it is complaining about?  It seems strange that it doesn't also complain at the same construct in the SELECT statement.  What column type is the iD column in your tblCheckout?

Comment: The ID column is a autonumber

Comment: Stop providing details in comments, and [edit] your question to put them there instead.

Comment: You didn't reply to my query about the DBMS you're using, but are you sure it supports "DELETE FROM" as well as the more usual "DELETE"?
Frankly, unless that is the problem, it is so unlikely that your DELETE fails while the SELECT does not, that if the code in your q is exactly what you are using, I would start thinking about other possible causes such as a memory overwrite.

Comment: @MartynA I edited my post with more info

Comment: OK, I will post an answer showing the correct way to do your insert in the next hour or so.

Comment: Are you sure you're using SQL Server? All searches for the error message return Access. And why do you put quotes around the currency value? A number is not a string. And you shouldn't use `FloatToStrF()` because it uses a localized decimal separator, which means you can get a comma instead of a dot. Get rid of all those issues by using a parameterized query, as MartynA will show you.

Comment: @Olivier I may, I'm not completely sure what dbms i am using. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Is your database in a .mdb file?

Comment: @Olivier:  I think you could be correct about Access, because the terms the OP has used, 'short text' and 'autonumber' don't sound very SqlServer-like to me

Comment: @MartynA Not to mention the strings enclosed in double quotes, while SQL Server only supports single quotes.

Comment: @Olivier the file is a .mdb

Comment: Which means you're using Access.

Comment: @Olivier:  Mebe, but with a q like this, I don't like to assume anything is correct, least of all string expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please start a new project with just the following items on the main form:

- A TAdoConnection configured to connect to your database;
- A TAdoQuery configured to use the TAdoConnection
- A TDataSource and TDBGrid configured to display the contents of the TAdoQuery.

Then, add the following code to the form

```
  const
    sSelect = 'select * from tblOrderItems';
    sInsert = 'insert into tblOrderItems(OrderItemID, OrderID, ItemID, ItemCategory, ItemPrice) '#13#10
    +  'values(:OrderItemID, :OrderID, :ItemID, :ItemCategory, :ItemPrice)';

    sOrderItemID = '0999';
    sOrderID = '1999';
    sItemID = '2999';
    sItemCategory = 'Bolt';
    fItemPrice = 5.99;

  procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin

    AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := sInsert;
    AdoQuery1.Prepared := True;

    AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('OrderItemID').Value:= sOrderItemID;
    AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('OrderID').Value := sOrderID;
    AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ItemID').Value := sItemID;
    AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ItemCategory').Value := sItemCategory;
    AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ItemPrice').Value := fItemPrice;

    AdoQuery1.ExecSQL;

    AdoQuery1.SQL.Text  := sSelect;
    AdoQuery1.Open;
  end;
```

Before compiling and running the program, review and change the values of the constants
so that they don't conflict with any rows already in your table.

The constant sInsert defines a so-called "parameterised SQL statement"  Inside the `Values`
list, the items :OrderItemID, :OrderID, etc, are placeholders which the AdoQuery will turn into
parameters whose values you can supply at run-time, as in the block after  `AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName(...`

You should *always* construct SQL statements this way and **not** by concatenating strings
as your code attempts to do.  It is far less error-prone, because it's easy to get into a
syntax muddle if you use DIY code and it also makes sure your queries are not prone
to [Sql-Injection exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which they would be if you
give the user the opportunity to edit the SQL.

If you are using a FireDAC FDQuery, this has `Params` (an FD data-type) rather thn Parameters
but they work in pretty much the same way - see the Online Help.

In future, please be a bit more careful to ensure you include important details, especially things like the **exact** line where the error occurs - which you can check by single-stepping through your code using the debugger - and things like the exact db-access components you are using. Also try to get details right like whether a column is a "short text" type or an autonumber.

For a problem that needs to be debugged, like this one, you should also provide a complete, [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not just a snippet of code.  Quite often, you will realise what the problem is while you are preparing the mre, so it helps you as well as us.

Comment: When I run this code in the same instance when I add new records to my database, I still get the same problem.

Comment: Sigh, and if you do it in the stand-alone project I asked you to use?  Anyway, I'll look into doing it in an MDB database tomorrow. I can't face spending any more time on it right now.

Comment: I figured it out thx. It worked on a standalone project, but I forgot to add the increasing integer at the end of one of the parameters.

Comment: Good, glad you sorted it out.  Meanwhile I checked that my answer works using an Access2016 database and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the problem is in incompatible floating point format.
Use parameters to avoid it.

Comment: An answer was already proposed and accepted, which provides far more detail. Please be sure to review existing answers before submitting new ones.